# How to install cloudera manager without cdh installation?

Tags: hadoop, monitoring, cloudera-manager

I have a hadoop environment with tarball which I downloaded at http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html#Download.

Then, I must use cloudera manager to monitor my mapreduce application.

is possible using cloudera manager without cdh installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudera Manager is useless without CDH. Any reason why you would not just use that? Usually the question is the other way around ("I have CDH installed, do I need to use Cloudera Manager?")

Comment: because, i already install hadoop environtment from http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html. hadoop web interface monitoring not provide information which i need. i think, i should change hadoop envorontment from cloudera. anyway, thanks to your reply.